# Pros and cons for pure virtual c++ coding

Tags: c++, inversion-of-control, pure-virtual

I'm coming form java background, had a conversation today with one of our C++ developer regarding to convert an existing code to have a pure virtual methods (interface) and to use them as dependency injection all over the code for better decoupling.

He tried to convince me that we should use them only when there is a "logic" in the code and in case the code is just collecting information from the PC it is not necessary.

Long story short, I'm looking for good reasons why to refactor the code and use IoC and pure virtual method instead of leaving the working coupled code as is.

Comment: @decltype_auto comon.. you invested time to read and seem like you want to help , this is the answer that you came with?

Comment: This question is better suited for stack exchange Programmers

Comment: Your question is somewhat incoherent; this might be a second language problem?  Still, it makes it hard to follow.  Insofar as it makes sense, it doesn't provide the information required to produce an objective answer.  Insofar as it provides the information required to answer, it isn't suitable for this website, which isn't a general "post questions for people who are better programmers to answer" website at this time.  Finally, "how is the weather in Maryland" is a reference to the location where the NSA is located; they install software that "collecting information from the PC".

Comment: @Eugene this question is a poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see [What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260) Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why use pure-virtual methods?

I try to write base class functions to provide default behaviour for all the interface methods.  I am surprised by how often these defaults simply generate some error handling (using the locally accepted mechanism).

For one example, I worked on code that received commands to set led states.  During development, the 'other software' sometimes would (mistakenly) request a colour explicitly dis-allowed by the requirements. ('Red' disallowed on status led 5)  My default functions generated the appropriate error message, and identified which 'other software' sent the erroneous request.

---

There are also cases that in some way have no appropriate default behaviour.  For these situations, I create pure-virtual methods.  Declaring the method pure virtual is **documenting** the idea that the base class will not provide the functionality, and is therefore requiring that all derived class must provide some code to support this concept.

---

"A pure virtual function or pure virtual method is a virtual function that is **required** to be implemented by a derived class that is not abstract" - Wikipedia

> good reasons why to refactor the code?

Readability.

Answer (score 2):

There are many reasons why you should or should not refactor existing code. Each situation is unique. If you are talking about some kind of project with large codebase and you want to refactor it's core which works good and properly tested than in 99% cases I'd recomend you don't do that. You can add more bugs to tested code without making really needed improvements. 
If code is just collecting some information you can extract interface for testing class that uses this object. If you don't use unit tests for some reasons than leave it as it is.
Overall you oponent is probably right, make interfaces when you really need them and write clean code with easy dependency extraction.